# Как вернуться в нужную сессию tmux

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

Допустим у меня есть 3 открытие сессии в системе. Через команду tmux list-sessions я могу увидеть список. Но как вернуться в нужную мне сессию из представленного списка?

Comment: Указать нужную в качестве параметра (по имени сессии)? По крайней мере так делает `screen`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tmux attach -t 1` - присоединиться к окну "1" (та цифра в квадратных скобках слева).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: обычно можно сократить до `tmux a -t name`. я еще всегда добавляю `tmux -2 a -t name`. `-2` добавляет в tmux поддержку расширенной цветовой схемы.